# How to allow telegram bot to check for optional arguements for a command

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to check if a user passes in an optional arguement when sending a command to the bot. The code I have written shown below.

```
bot.onText(/\/command (.+)?/, function(msg, match) {
    let str = match[1];

    if (str != null) {
       console.log("not null");
    } else
       console.log("null");
});
```

Now when I test the code by passing an arguement, the output is printed. However, when the optional arguement is not passed there is no output. is my regex incorrect or is the way that I am executing incorrect?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex has a space between command and opening bracket. `/\/command (.+)?/`.
So matching a Regex with only `/command` will return entire null instead of a valid array.
Try using `/\/command(\s.+)?/`.